# H2o.ai fails to query openLDAP passes 'cn' instead of 'uid'

Tags: ldap, h2o, openldap

I configured h2o application to use openLDAP configuration referring to the link:
https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.3/latest-stable/doc/tutorials/ldap.html
Added userNameAttribute=uid to ovreride 'cn' to use 'uid' field instead.

However it is not working. The query getting passed on LDAP still has cn=user_id instead of uid=user_id.

Am I doing something wrong or is a bug?

ldap.conf:

````
    ai.h2o.org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    useLdaps="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    hostname="ldap.h2o.ai"
    port="389"
    bindDn="cn=admin,dc=h2o,dc=ai"
    bindPassword="h2o"
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="true"
    userBaseDn="ou=users,dc=h2o,dc=ai"
    userNameAttribute="uid";
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

userIdAttribute="uid" worked for me.
Now the authentication from LDAP is successful, however now it's failing with same exception mentioned at:
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2648, and the suggested fix is NOT included in h2o.jar, hence the failure.
#h2o team needs to update the h2o.jar with this fix.